How to implement nested classical controls in Qiskit?
Suppose we have the following scenario. On a set of $n$ qubits we measure the first qubit, then we apply either qc0 or qc1 circuit depending on the result, where both circuits measure the second qubit and contain further branching.
The problem is that this code
root = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
root.h(0)

qc0 = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc0.x(0)
qc0.measure([0], [0])

qc1 = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc1.h(0)
qc1.measure([0], [0])

root.measure([0], [0])
root.if_else((root.clbits[0], 0),qc0,qc1,range(1,3),range(1,3))

root.decompose().draw('mpl')

shows the error
CircuitError: "Could not locate provided bit: Clbit(ClassicalRegister(2, 'c'), 0). Has it been added to the QuantumCircuit?"

which looks like a bug (see https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/12084), while this code
root = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
root.h(0)

qc0 = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc0.x(0)
qc0.measure([0], [0])
with qc0.if_test((qc0.clbits[0], 0)) as else_:
  qc0.y(1)
with else_:
  qc0.z(1)

qc1 = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc1.h(0)
qc1.measure([0], [0])
with qc1.if_test((qc1.clbits[0], 0)) as else_:
  qc1.y(1)
with else_:
  qc1.z(1)

root.measure([0], [0])
with root.if_test((root.clbits[0], 0)) as else_:
  root.append(qc0, range(1,3), range(1,3))
with else_:
  root.append(qc1, range(1,3), range(1,3))

root.decompose().draw('mpl')

shows the error
NotImplementedError: IfElseOp cannot be classically controlled through Instruction.c_if. Please nest it in an IfElseOp instead.

Is there a way to avoid the problems and implement nested classical ifs somehow?

Was able to do it with explicit qubit referencing, but can't answer my own question because checkbox wasn't checked, lol. Here is the code:

qr = QuantumRegister(3, 'q')
cr = ClassicalRegister(3, 'c')
root = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
root.h(qr[0])
qc0 = QuantumCircuit(qr[1:3],cr[1:3])
qc0.x(0)
qc0.measure([0], [0])
qc00 = QuantumCircuit(qr[2:3],cr[2:3])
qc00.x(0)
qc01 = QuantumCircuit(qr[2:3],cr[2:3])
qc01.h(0)
qc0.if_else((cr[1], 0),qc00,qc01,qr[2:3],cr[2:3])
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(qr[1:3],cr[1:3])
qc1.h(0)
qc1.measure([0], [0])
root.measure(qr[0], cr[0])
root.if_else((cr[0], 0),qc0,qc1,qr[1:3],cr[1:3])
root.decompose().draw('mpl')
